# click event and mousedown event conflict

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to bind element(s) with the on click event at the same time, bind it also on mousedown, so its kinda like if user click anywhere and not on element that has a class of .main and its children then don't trigger the mousedown event, but the problem is it triggers the event unto its children of .main and the onclick event that bound to its children was not triggered. Any ideas, help please? but if you remove the mousedown event, the onclick event that was bound to the .main children were triggered.

```js
for(var i=0;i<document.querySelectorAll('.main li').length;i++){
  document.querySelectorAll('.main li')[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
   alert(this.querySelector('a').textContent);
 });
}
//hook a touchstart and mousedown event 
addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){  
  var t = /touch/.test(event.type) ? event.targetTouches[0] : event.target;
  if( t.classList.contains('main') ){

    return false;
  }else{
    alert('not clicked on body');
  }
},true);
```

```css
.main{
height:200px;
background:red;
width:300px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main">
  <li><a href="#">test 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">test 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">test 3</a></li>
<ul>
```

Comment: This can never work as the `mousedown` is always triggered _before_ the click event, since `mouseup` is still due to happen. Otherwise, you can use something like `stopPropagation` on the event to prevent the event from triggering on your parent.

Answer (score -1):

Stop the event on mouse down:

`$( "p" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  // Do something
});`

Comment: @JuliverGalleto What do mean by this is not jquery? https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/ I think the API of jQuery is wrong then.